# Parallel MOSFETs to get more current (40A adjustable current source)

Tags: mosfet, current, parallel

In [my previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400514/adjustable-high-current-source-40a) about an adjustable constant current source, I was advised to use an Op-Amp and a MOSFET to generate a current source that I could adjust with a variable input voltage.

The goal is to test some fuses (normal operating current and time/current to fuse). To do this I would need some 50A (at least).

Here is the original suggested circuit:

[image: current source]

(Image source: [Learning about Electronics](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Current-source-circuit.php))

The resistor would be replaced by a much lower value (in mOhm to handle to high current). To avoid thermal problems, I'd like to parallel MOSFETs (4 devices). Shall I use one Op-Amp per MOSFET (replicate the whole circuit four times) or shall I use only one Op-Amp?

I think I understand how the single MOSFET circuit works, but I'd need some help to scale it up and avoid me toasting my poor single MOSFET with 40A DC !!

The idea would be to use a car battery as main power source. Vdd around 12V and plenty of amps!

Comment: @ Akira Doe .We must Know what Vdd is .Power dissipation and SOA are big reliability issues here .

Comment: @Autistic : I would use a car battery to power the circuit. 12V and plenty of current. For normal operation, I'd need to test it to 15A (max continuous discharge of my 18650 batteries that I'd like to fuse) and I would like to design the fuse to melt quickly at 50A,

Comment: Wouldn't it simply be easier to make a [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) and simply use the MOSFET(s) the way they are meant to be used together with a low-pass LC filter to reduce the ripples?

Comment: [Thermal runaway in MOSFETs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361407/dc-operation-for-irfz44-mosfet-soa-curve-max-current-at-40v)

Comment: How fast do you need to cause the current to rise?

Comment: *To avoid thermal problems...* Why not just use one device and mount it on a suitable heatsink?  You'll need that much heat-sinking anyway with four devices, spread over four heatsinks.  It's usually cheaper to get one big one.

Comment: @Spehro : I don't really care. I'll use it to test the current needed to blow a fuse. I expect the fuse to blow in around one second so the rising time is not critical.

Answer (score 19):

You have two problems

1. Paralleling MOSEFTs in this mode is unstable. However, you could parallel the outputs of several totally independent current sources, each with its own power device, Rs and opamp.
2. Most MOSFETs will not like operating in linear mode like this, they are designed and specified for switching operation. Internally, MOSFETs are hundreds, if not thousands, of separate small FETs. When switched fully on, they share current nicely, their resistance changes with temperature so that any hotspots on the die shed current and cool. When operating in linear mode, they are unstable, with \$V_{GS}\$ changing with temperature so that any hotspots on the die get hotter and quickly run away thermally.

If you check out the Safe Operating Area (SOA) graph for many power MOSFETs, you will find curves for various pulse lengths, but rarely a DC curve, they are simply not specified for dissipating significant power under DC conditions. During a short pulse in the linear region, or during a transition between off to on, the die does start to run away, but the linear event is over before any damage is done. If you check the SOA graph for BJTs, you will always find a DC line, they will work to DC.

You have three options.

1. Find FETs that are specified for DC operation in the linear region. These are few and far between, and relatively expensive. They are usually intended for audio amplifiers.
2. Operate the FET at a fraction of its rated switching dissipation, perhaps 20%. This is probably safe.
3. Use BJTs. Darlingtons often have current gains above 1000, so do not present too much of a load to your current servo opamp.

Comment: Can you elaborate on a ? I've used mosfet for this type of regulation for years and never had any stability issue. They wouldn't be used for audio amp if that was the case. For b many, many cheap mosfet are rated DC operation on linear region, take BUK7Y102-100B as one example. BJT will require more complex driving circuit.

Comment: For the little story, my previous company has a machine with about 2'000 paralleled mosfets delivering a regulated 20'000 amps on pulse. There are more than 1000 of these equipment operating for about 8 years, and haven't seen any mosfet failure so far.

Comment: @Damien The key word is "pulse". Is that your intended use? Everyone seems to think you indent to leave it on like a welder. Speaking of which, an arc welder is exactly the sort of adjustable current source you're looking for, but it's AC.

Comment: @piojo that was for the larger scale, it's also being used on DC at lower amps. The key is to stay within power dissipation.

Comment: Mosfet are better suited to be in parallel as already answered here on the two answers, as bjt will have gain matching issue and thermal runaway https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77045/transistors-in-parallel

Comment: @Damien Yes, BUK7Y102-100B looks like a reasonable one, needs less derating for DC than usually required, which is about 40W on the SOA, compared to 60W max dissipation.

Comment: I should add that I misspoke. Almost all arc welders are DC. But from what I've read, the current will fluctuate along with the AC waveform, maybe even going down to zero at the zero crossing.

Comment: @piojo Arc welders may be loosly regulated DC but they're definitely DC, and the current cannot go to zero at the zero crossing.  If current went to zero, the arc would break.

Comment: @NateStrickland I could be wrong in my above statement, but there are definitely bad welders where the arc will break at low currents. There are DC welders that can use a difficult rod like 6010, and DC welders that can't. Additionally, there are AC welders, and the arc does not break, provided you use welding rods with suitable flux (like 6011 instead of 6010).

Comment: @Damien: I am not too familiar with SMD components. I have large heatsinks (30cm*20cm*5cm fins) with threaded holes on which I could easily  mount TO220 Fets. Would you have a recommendation for MOSFETs similar to BUK7Y102-100B in TO220 ? Maybe BUK7575-100A ? There is a DC line in the SOA with 10A at 10V. I could try to put 8 in parallel to be safe.

Comment: @AkiraDoe from the graph of this Mos, you can probably have 5-6A at 12V in DC so I would put at least 10 of them.

Answer (score 4):

Use one opamp that is able to drive a fairly high current (20+mA) and add a 1k resistor at each gate of the mosfet.

A good example is an audio amplifier, you don't need to care about the regulation circuit as you are using a op-amp but it shows the Mosfet being paralleled.

As the mosfet has a [positive temperature dependence](https://www.onsemi.cn/PowerSolutions/document/AND8199-D.PDF) in relation to the temperature, they will automatically compensate in current flow and avoid thermal runaway.

[image]

Comment: When operated in linear mode most MOSFETs (if not all) do not have a negative temperature coefficient and they can suffer thermal runaway rather badly if care is not taken.

Comment: @Andyaka you are incorrect, here is a reference: https://www.onsemi.cn/PowerSolutions/document/AND8199-D.PDF

Comment: You haven't read that document carefully enough -1. Look at figure 1 and ask your self what is the temperature coefficient when Vgs is below 6.3 volts. Read the words under figure 4 and learn.

Comment: @Andyaka The thermal-runaway situation occurs when you use large
devices at low current-limit settings.

Comment: @Andyaka mosfet has positive temperature coefficient and the current will reduce with heat. You didn't read the document. It's cell WITHIN a mosfet that might thermal runaway in what you are referring, but this has nothing to do with having several mosfets in parallel.

Comment: @Andyaka check this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77045/transistors-in-parallel

Comment: Read gsills answer and note that in the "top" answer the guy answering has been reminded in comments about how misguided his suggestions are.

Comment: I think an important part of the above circuit which hasn't been noted (and I think contributes to it working), is that each MOSFET has its own source resistor (the 1R- R18,R22,R26,R30 etc), which helps the MOSFETs to share the load current.

Comment: @user85471, the resistor a part of the mosfet balancing between high side and low side to have 0-crossing, it it not needed in the OP application.